# Hide the Dock icon in Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt

I have the same question as [How to hide the Java SWT program icon in the Dock when the application is in the tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246766/how-to-hide-the-java-swt-program-icon-in-the-dock-when-the-application-is-in-the)

I have tried the solution given there but it didn't work, probably because `Dapple.awt.UIElement="true"` works only for AWT and my app is an SWT application. After going through many similar questions, I came to know that changing `LSUIElement` value to `1` will not show any icon in the dock.

But how do I change its value? Can I change it programmatically? If not, where will be my `.plist` file? I don't seem to have such a file. I am using Eclipse Juno in Mac OS X 10.9.4

Edit: I have seen this [Eclipse info.plist file for OSX and Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495752/eclipse-info-plist-file-for-osx-and-windows-application) also and followed the process the answer 
.But then how do i open the .app file.  I tried "open MyApp.app" from cmd.I get the error LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810

Comment: This won't help you, but... You shouldn't alter the .app contents once it has been installed.  This strategy won't work for non-administrator users.  It won't work for sandboxed apps.  Whatever the correct solution is, it needs to be one that does not alter the .app contents.

Comment: Have you found solution ?